# How To make the input add values every time the button is clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got buttons to click , and when its clicked i want the value to be incremented by the same value that is being clicked;
here is my html

```
          <div  id="setTimer">
                <div class="spans">
                  <span   class="timeSet" >1</span>
                  <span  class="timeSet">2</span>
                  <span  class="timeSet">3</span>
                  <span  class="timeSet">4</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spans">
                    <span  class="timeSet">5</span>
                   <span  class="timeSet">6</span>
                   <span  class="timeSet">7</span>
                   <span  class="timeSet">8</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spans">
                    <span  class="timeSet">9</span>
                    <span  class="timeSet">0</span>
                    <span  class="timeSet">+30s</span>
                </div>             
            </div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0
        var btnCountOutput = $('#btnCountOutput');
    var txt = $(this);
    $('.timeSet').click(function(txt){
        count++;
        if(count > 3){
            console.log('that cant be done!');
            return false;
        }
        var output = txt.currentTarget.innerHTML;
        output++;
        var num = parseFloat(output);
        var inputOut = btnCountOutput.val(num);
        console.log(num);
        console.log(count);
    });
});
```

**Html for the output**

```
<div class="timeCount">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buttonclick Counter" class="col" 
     id="btnCountOutput">
```

**CSS if needed**

```
#setTimer .spans{
margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
 #setTimer span{
   width: 15px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius:50%;
   background: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**well , just like *Java Script* where i could just write;**

```
  btnCountOutput.value += num;
```

*That every time the button is clicked , just add on the output any value that is clicked*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the value of the text box then add it to the number you pass in. After the addition happens, you can then set the value of the text box again. I added a variable called `currentCount` as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/487eaopt/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0
  var btnCountOutput = $('#btnCountOutput');
  var txt = $(this);
  $('.timeSet').click(function(txt) {
    count++;
    if (count > 3) {
      console.log('that cant be done!');
      return false;
    }
    var output = txt.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    output++;
    var num = parseFloat(output);
    var currentCount = btnCountOutput.val(); // Grab the current value
    var inputOut = btnCountOutput.val(+num + +currentCount); // Add the two values together and set the text box (make sure to convert string to number)
    console.log(num);
    console.log(count);
  });
});
```

You also don't need your `parseFloat` function. You do need some function to make sure you're string gets converted to a number, but you want either `Number`, `parseInt`, or `+`. `parseFloat` isn't needed unless you'll be working with decimal values.

Comment: Yes I want to be number but the reason I used (parseFloat) is because I want more than 2digits displayed on the screen so I thought that could be the best way to do it , another thing is the "currentCount variable that you just added ..actually what it does is gets the current and "add" to the number that is entered ..well that worked but not exactly what I want is that , if I am to click button named 4 let it be 4 e.g. (4:4:4) or if I click 2 (2:2:2) I tried that in plain js and worked but in jquery still a problem ...thanks though! ); i thought of using switch statement anyway!, Though not s

Comment: Actually thanks so much ..just did something and removed the prefix (+) num and the prefix  (+)current Count and it worked as I wanted ...thanks once again  sooooooo much!